# How to parse two json one using jquery and other using web workers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to parse two JSON files,one i am parsing using getJSON and one using Web workers.But output of only JSON parsed using getJSON is coming.Output of JSON parsed through Web Workers hides behind the other output

Comment: You'll need to post your code...

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're doing this? Have a look at these statistics http://igorminar.github.io/webworker-json-perf/